# How to plot two curves on the same canvas in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

Here is the code for generating simulated data:

```
eff = seq(.1, 1, .1)
method = c('method1', 'method2')
xxxd = expand.grid(eff=eff, method=method)
xxxd$power = c(pow1, pow2)
pow1 = seq(.2, .7, length.out=10)
pow2 = seq(.4, .8, length.out=10)
pow1 = pow1 + rnorm(10, .05, .01)
pow2 = pow2 + rnorm(10, .05, .01)
xxxd$power = c(pow1, pow2)
```

And here is the data:

```
   eff  method   power
1  0.1 method1 0.25942
2  0.2 method1 0.32162
3  0.3 method1 0.36329
4  0.4 method1 0.41286
5  0.5 method1 0.47904
6  0.6 method1 0.52165
7  0.7 method1 0.58191
8  0.8 method1 0.64884
9  0.9 method1 0.69488
10 1.0 method1 0.73656
11 0.1 method2 0.44882
12 0.2 method2 0.49010
13 0.3 method2 0.54465
14 0.4 method2 0.58675
15 0.5 method2 0.63173
16 0.6 method2 0.69120
17 0.7 method2 0.71456
18 0.8 method2 0.77440
19 0.9 method2 0.81033
20 1.0 method2 0.85103
```

The figure that I would like to produce is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your data appears to be in long format to begin with, it is trivial to use with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xxxd, aes(eff, power, colour = method)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

The help pages for ggplot2 are really quite wonderful: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to be doing the `lines()` function. First use `plot()` with one of your "methods", and then use `lines()` on the second. The arguments are identical to `plot`. It's just that it adds the new curve to an existing plot rather than creating a new window. `?lines` should clarify more.

Comment: how can i do this with ggplot2 or lattice?